# Background color cut off after viewport, CSS

Tags: css, viewport

When I stretch my browser window so no scrollbar appears, my content is fine. However, if I shrink my browser to a small height where a scrollbar appears, my background-color is cut off past the viewport. Here is the code, jsfiddle at bottom:

```
<div id="container">

<header>
<p>ZLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</header>

<div role="main">

<div id="content-listing">
<p>ZLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div><!--end content-listing-->

<div id="content-display">
<article>
<section class="prop-desc">
<p>ZLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>ZLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>ZLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
</article>
</div><!--end content-display-->

</div><!--end main-->

</div><!--end container-->
```

And the CSS:

```
/* ///// Globals ///// */
body{background-color:green;font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;}
body,html{height:100%;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical{height:10px;background:#fff;}
::-webkit-scrollbar {width:10px;height:5px;background:yellow;margin-right:5px;}
img{max-width:100%;}

/* ///// Layout ///// */
#container{width:90%;height:100%;}/*960px*/

header{width:17.708333333333%;float:left;background-color:blue;height:100%;}/*170px*/

div[role=main]{width:82.291666666667%;float:left;height:100%;}/*790px*/

#content-listing{width:29.113924050633%;float:left;background-color:red;height:100%;}/*230px*/

#content-display{width:70.886075949367%;float:left;background-color:orange;height:100%;color:#fff;}/*560px*/
```

To demonstrate what I mean, click the fiddle below and resize your window so there is no scrollbar and again so that a vertical scrollbar appears:

http://jsfiddle.net/g2748/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way I solved this was I added `padding-bottom:20010px;margin-bottom: -20000px;` to the 3 columns. I adapted this technique from here:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail

I then added `min-height:100%` and `overflow:hidden` to the `#container` div. It's a little hacky bit it did the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/g2748/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try **removing** the `height: 100%;` from your ***divs***.  It should work.